# Issue Gillespie SSA

Tags: r

I keep getting the same error and can't figure out what the error is in regards to

```
Error in ssa(x0 = x0, a = a, nu = nu, parms = parms, tf = tf, method = ssa.d(),  : 
  inconsistent system dimensions (unequal 'nu' tessallation)
```

I think it concerns the matrix, but I am not 100% sure. I have tried changing it but am still running into the same issue.

```
nu <- matrix(c( -1,  0,  0, +1, +1, -1,  0,  0,  0 , 0,  # S
                +1, -1,  0,  0,  0,  0, -1,  0,  0,  0,  # E
                 0, +1, -1,  0,  0,  0,  0, -1,  0, -1, # I
                 0,  0, +1, -1,  0,  0,  0,  0, -1,  0, # R
                 0,  0,  0,  0, +1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1), # BD
             nrow=5,byrow=TRUE)
```

Comment: Unfortunately we can't help without more information (e.g., a [mcve] ...) In case it helps, the test/error code is implemented [here](https://github.com/rcannood/GillespieSSA/blob/master/R/ssa.R#L284-L288) ...